# Cannot destructure property 'imageUrl' of 'response.body' as it is undefined

Tags: typeerror

I am using node v18 and angular v16 to add images through npm install @kolkov/angular-editor package.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'imageUrl' of 'response.body' as it is undefined.
getting this error in consloe while adding image.

I am getting proper res in of url link from backend not able to receive in angular and add in texteditor .
uploadUrl: environment.baseUrl + '/uploadTextEditorImages',
upload: (file: File) => { ... }
uploadWithCredentials: false,
sanitize: true,
toolbarPosition: 'top',
toolbarHiddenButtons: [['bold', 'italic'],['fontSize']]

this is the code i am using in config.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK9Oq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT7yM.png)